# Looping over filtered find and performing an operation

Tags: bash, terminal, pandoc

I have a garbage dump of a bunch of Wordpress files and I'm trying to convert them all to Markdown.

The script I wrote is:

```
htmlDocs=($(find . -print | grep -i '.*[.]html'))
for html in "${htmlDocs[@]}"
            do
                P_MD=${html}.markdown
                echo "${html} \> ${P_MD}"
                pandoc --ignore-args -r html -w markdown < "${html}" | awk 'NR > 130' | sed '/<div class="site-info">/,$d'  > "${P_MD}"                
            done
```

As far as I understand, the first line should be making an array of all `html` files in all subdirectories, then the for loop has a line to create a variable with the Markdown name (followed by a debugging echo), then the actual `pandoc` command to do the conversion.

One at a time, this command works.

However, when I try to execute it, OSX gives me:

```
$ ./pandoc_convert.command 
./pandoc_convert.command: line 1: : No such file or directory
./pandoc_convert.command: line 1: : No such file or directory
```

o_0

Help?

Comment: are you certain you have html files under the bash file root somewhere?  Try running `find . -print | grep -i '.*[.]html'` under the same directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be many reasons why the script fails, because the way you create the array is incorrect:

```
htmlDocs=($(find . -print | grep -i '.*[.]html'))
```

Arrays are assigned in the form: `NAME=(VALUE1 VALUE2 ... )`, where `NAME` is the name of the variable, `VALUE1`, `VALUE2`, and the rest are fields separated with characters that are present in the `$IFS` (input field separator) variable. Suppose you find a file name with spaces. Then the expression will create separate items in the array.

Another issue is that the expression doesn't handle globbing, i.e. file name generation based on the shell expansion of special characters such as `*`:

```
mkdir dir.html
touch \ *.html
touch a\ b\ c.html

a=($(find . -print | grep -i '.*[.]html'))
for html in "${a[@]}"; do echo ">>>${html}<<<"; done
```

*Output*

```
>>>./a<<<
>>>b<<<
>>>c.html<<<
>>>./<<<
>>>a b c.html<<<
>>>dir.html<<<
>>> *.html<<<
>>>./dir.html<<<
```

I know two ways to fix this behavior: 1) temporarily disable globbing, and 2) use the `mapfile` command.

**Disabling Globbing**

```
# Disable globbing, remember current -f flag value
[[ "$-" == *f* ]] || globbing_disabled=1
set -f

IFS=$'\n' a=($(find . -print | grep -i '.*[.]html'))
for html in "${a[@]}"; do echo ">>>${html}<<<"; done

# Restore globbing
test -n "$globbing_disabled" && set +f
```

*Output*

```
>>>./  .html<<<
>>>./a b c.html<<<
>>>./ *.html<<<
>>>./dir.html<<<
```

**Using `mapfile`**

The `mapfile` is introduced in Bash 4. The command reads lines from the standard input into an indexed array:

```
mapfile -t a < <(find . -print | grep -i '.*[.]html')
for html in "${a[@]}"; do echo ">>>${html}<<<"; done
```

**The `find` Options**

The `find` command selects all types of nodes, including directories. You should use the `-type` option, e.g. `-type f` for files.

If you want to filter the result set with a regular expression use `-regex` option, or `-iregex` for case-insensitive matching:

```
mapfile -t a < <(find . -type f -iregex .*\.html$)
for html in "${a[@]}"; do echo ">>>${html}<<<"; done
```

*Output*

```
>>>./  .html<<<
>>>./a b c.html<<<
>>>./ *.html<<<
```

**`echo` vs. `printf`**

Finally, [don't use `echo` in new software](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo). Use `printf` instead:

```
mapfile -t a < <(find . -type f -iregex .*\.html$)
for html in "${a[@]}"; do printf '>>>%s<<<\n' "$html"; done
```

**Alternative Approach**

However, I would rather pipe a loop with a `read`:

```
find . -type f -iregex .*\.html$ | while read line
do
  printf '>>>%s<<<\n' "$line"
done
```

In this example, the `read` command reads a line from the standard input and stores the value into `line` variable.

Although I like the `mapfile` feature, I find the code with the pipe more clear.

Comment: The pipe worked nicely. I apparently had to resave the file (I suppose something was corrupt about the first one??) because initially NONE of your answers were working, but that did it: https://gist.github.com/tigerhawkvok/f91b5ae61ab8b9ccac6f3ca6e13473f4

Clearly, I'm new to Bash -- my usual answer has been "make a Python script", but I wanted to do this natively.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the bash shebang and set IFS to handle spaces in folders and filenames:

```
#!/bin/bash
SAVEIFS=$IFS
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")

htmlDocs=($(find . -print | grep -i '.*[.]html'))
for html in "${htmlDocs[@]}"
do
                P_MD=${html}.markdown
                echo "${html} \> ${P_MD}"
                pandoc --ignore-args -r html -w markdown < "${html}" | awk 'NR > 130' | sed '/<div class="site-info">/,$d'  > "${P_MD}" 
done
IFS=$SAVEIFS
```